# Регулярное выражение в с#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Почему такая конструкция

```
Regex re = new Regex("href=\"(.*?)\" id=\"lowres\"");
```

Выдает вместо ссылки ещё и href с id, в общем все выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно выводите результат. Вам нужно не полное совпадение, а только группа (то что в скобках)

```
Regex re = new Regex("href=\"(.*?)\" id=\"lowres\"");
Match match = re.Match(text);
while (match.Success) {       
    string url = match.Groups[1].Value; // Вот тут url из href
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```